# PYTHONPATH Getting set in Bash Shell to incorrect value

Tags: python, bashrc, fish

OS: macOS Sierra Beta 6
Python: 2.7
Shell: Fish

I am having issues with my PYTHONPATH environmental variable being set correctly.

In my fish_config file, I have this line setting up PYTHONPATH:

```
set -gx PYTHONPATH "/opt/additionalPath" "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages";
```

But when I launch python, I get this output when I try to look at the path:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/opt/additionalPath\x1e/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
>>>
```

Notice the \x1e between the paths that I am adding.

If I launch the bash shell from fish and echo $PYTHONPATH, I get this output:

```
/opt/additionalPath/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I know that those paths are supposed to be separate by a colon but I can't figure out where that is being done.  My theory is that something in the bash shell is setting the path in the fish shell but I am running out of ideas.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a list in fish for `PYTHONPATH`, you have to use a single string with `:` as a separator as you would do in bash:

`set -gx PYTHONPATH "/opt/additionalPath:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages"`

See [this bug report](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2125) for some more info.

Comment: Also, if you're using fish 2.3.0 or newer, and thus can use the new `string` builtin, you can do it this way: `set -gx PYTHONPATH (string join : /opt/additionalPath /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages)`